# in swift 2 how to remove optional word?

Tags: macos

I was developing an app in which this error occurred so how to remove optional word from answer in swift 2?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You have to unwrap it.

```
if let text = catAge.text {
    print(text)
}
```